# How to specify if a T4 file should produce any output

Tags: visual-studio, split, t4, dto

I am using T4 for generation of some DTO classes + mappers.

I am splitting the files in a number of re-usable bits (some of which containing common methods, some others common procedures) and including them into the T4 templates that will produce my output - which is all good.

My problem is that the re-usable .tt files will try and produce their own output and fail (because they are coupled to some other .tt files) every time I make a change to them, which plain sucks.

I am pretty sure I saw somewhere some directive to specify a given file shouldn't try and produce any output, but I can't seem to track it back.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the properties (select file and press F4) of the T4 files for which you'd like to suppress output, clear the 'Custom Tool' entry.

Comment: this sounds exactly what I need - is there any way of doing this from the markup?

Comment: @JohnIdol - I don't believe there is a way to suppress the output in the mark up of the T4 file itself. As Preet says, the setting is controlled by the extistence of a <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator> element in the project file so you can delete that as an alternative to clearing the property via the VS GUI.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify invalid extension to suppress the output of your template, for example:

```
<#@ output extension="\n" #>
```

Comment: +1. This is lovely and horrible! It works perfectly for our purposes. We are redirecting the output of our TT file to another location, and needed to suppress the regular output.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough 'StackOverflow street cred' to reply to Stanislav Kniazev's answer, so will have to post my own here. Thanks for the lead Stanislav Kniazev.

The following worked; but if you are using a T4 syntax highlighter (like Tangible T4) you will find that it stuffs up the highlighting.

> <#@ output extension="\n" #>

So I found setting the extension to something that is not an escape char like this:

> <#@ output extension="" #>

and then in the code section programmatically setting the file extension, like this:

> Host.SetFileExtension("\n");

T4 highlighting is then restored.

Answer (score 1):

rename them to .ttinclude and see how that goes for ya....

Comment: If the file was already added as a T4 file, the 'Custom Tool' will still be defined.  Changing the extension from 'tt' to 'ttinclude' will not clear this property.